# Separating ternary and equals operator

Tags: c++

```cpp
bool boolean = true;
T* a = nullptr;
T* b = nullptr;

// What I have:
(boolean ? a : b) = new T();

// What I want:
??? which = boolean ? a : b;
which = new T();
```

How can I split that expression into two lines? At the moment I use up this ternary operator all over the place, so I think it would be better to just have it as `which`, and I don't want to repeat myself. Also, what I currently have is incredibly confusing to read.

Comment: This is attempting to write Javascript code in C++. C++ is not Javascript. In modern C++ there's rarely a need to use `new` and `delete`, as containers will do all the work for you, and will handle memory allocation correctly.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik How should I do it instead then?

Comment: That depends on what this function, class, or template needs to do, overall. Why are there two discrete objects, and why does one of them need to be constructed? What is that supposed to accomplish, what problem does that solve?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am building a Binary Tree class, so they correspond to the left and right branches accordingly. This was the part that either added a new `Node` or iterated the temporary variable to a new `Node`.

Comment: The usual implementation will use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::make_shared` to handle the allocation for you, and avoid memory leaks.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you for sharing that info. I'll make sure to look into those  so that I can do things more correctly :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define it as reference:

```
auto& which = boolean ? a : b; // or T*& which = ...
which = new T();

...

delete which;
```

Comment: @JaackoTorus It's the exact type of `which` in `auto& which = boolean ? a : b;`, I added it as supplementary.

Comment: No, I wasn't saying you're wrong, I just would never have guessed to do that. You are brilliant, thank you.

Comment: @JaackoTorus I know, I just want to tell you that it's the exact type you need.